# Javascript - Object, for loop starting at 2

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I have objects looking like this.

```
foo = {
    0 : {
        'bar' : 'baz',
        'qux' : 'quux',
        'this' : { 'hello' : 'yes' } // this is the object I want to extract
    }
    1 : {
        'bar' : 'baz',
        'qux' : 'quux',
        'this' : { 'hello' : 'yes' } // extract
    }
    2 : {
        'bar' : 'baz',
        'qux' : 'quux',
        'this' : { 'hello' : 'yes' }, // extract
        'that' : { 'hello' : 'no' } // extract
    }
}
```

with a for loop like this I get to loop through every object:

```
for(var i in foo){
  ...
}
```

The problem is that I only want to pull the data from the third and greater child object than **('this')** from each object.

Comment: Object properties are not ordered. Use arrays instead.

Comment: Objects are unordered. There isn't really a concept of a "first" or "second" key-value pair. Are you just trying to get all keys that happen to have values that are objects?

Comment: If I always know that they will come in this order?

Comment: Use this format and regular `for` loop: `foo = [{},{},{}]`

Comment: @Philip: There *is* no order. That's just the way they're being displayed.

Comment: But I can call them with unique keys?

Comment: [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues)  Although ECMAScript makes iteration order of objects implementation-dependent, it may appear that all major browsers support an iteration order based on the earliest added property coming first (at least for properties not on the prototype). However, in the case of Internet Explorer, when one uses delete on a property, some confusing behavior results

Comment: Aha I see, looks like I will have to make an array of it instead.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4: I think Chrome iterates over the properties in sort order of the property names. Numerical ones first. Quick test: `var a = {foo: 0, 1: 0, 0: 0}; for(var p in a) { console.log(p)}`

Comment: @FelixKling I think that applies only for properties which are created implicity. Quick test: `var a = {};(a.c=0,a.a=1,a.b=2);for ( var p in a) { console.log("%s : %s",p,a[p])}`

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4: Interesting. So this mainly applies to object literals. But that alone is a reason to not assume anything about the order (e.g. FF 20 iterates over the properties in the order they are listed in the literal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specified order for *object keys* in ECMAscript. You really should use an *Javascript Array* if you have indexed key names nonetheless.

If you need to have a plain *Object*, you might want to use `Object.keys()` alongside `Array.prototype.forEach` and `.sort()`, like

```
Object.keys( foo ).sort().forEach(function( i ) {
});
```

---

If you can't rely on ES5, you have no choice but to do the work manually.

```
var keys = [ ];

for(var key in foo) {
    if( foo.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
        keys.push( key );
    }
}

keys.sort();

for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
}
```

---

However, you really should just use an *Array* in the first place, so you can skip the dirty work.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use Object.keys with IE.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I think that I will make an array of it instead.! =)

Comment: Wouldn't `var cnt = 1,cur;while (cur = foo[++cnt]) {...}` work too, though it still doesn't make much sense using an object